# Preserve quotes when using shlex.split

Tags: python, shlex

How can one preserve the quotes around "value with spaces" when using shlex.split()?

```
s = "SOME_VAR=\"value with spaces\" VAR2=value2"
shlex.split(s)
['SOME_VAR=value with spaces', 'VAR2=value2']
```

Thank you

Comment: Seems like shlex is an actual parser, so you'd have to escape the special characters. For instance, this parses correctly: `"SOME_VAR=\\\"value\\ with\\ spaces\\\" VAR2=value2"`. I don't know exactly how you could do and escape those characters, since you'd pretty much have to create a parser and re-implement shlex...

Comment: What's your reasoning for wanting the maintain the quotes? Would it be enough to assume that if the value contains spaces that it was once originally quoted?

Comment: Salt uses shlex.split to split parameters for calls to msiexec.

https://github.com/saltstack/salt/blob/develop/salt/modules/win_pkg.py#L1132

I am trying to provide a key/value pair to msiexec where the value may contain spaces. 

If the quotes are removed, msiexec treats everything after the first space as a parameter and fails.

Answer (score 0):

Your choice of a Python tool may not be optimal.

How about:

```
$ cat /tmp/tmp.py
import csv
import StringIO

s = "SOME_VAR=\"value with spaces\" VAR2=value2"
reader = csv.reader(StringIO.StringIO(s), csv.excel)

for i in reader:
  print i

$ python /tmp/tmp.py
['SOME_VAR="value with spaces" VAR2=value2']
```