# Python shlex posix usage dilemma

Tags: python, shlex

I came to this dilemma while working on improving my semi-automated library management for an ECAD software (namely KiCad), what is below is only an example which I hope represents the issue I ran into.

The library file contains multiple lines and sometimes the line can have double-quotes embedded in one of its fields, which is managed by adding an escape `\` char. For instance:

```
string = "\"This is a \\\"difficult\\\" problem\" please help"
print(f'string = {string}')
```

will output:

```
string = "This is a \"difficult\" problem" please help
```

I need to split this string using shlex (this was the solution of choice, I would like to keep it), following those 2 conditions:

1. "This is... problem" needs to be a **single** list item
2. the double-quotes around both "This ... problem" and "difficult" need to be conserved.

Note: In this example, the two other words `please` and `help` do not require special treatment.

I've tried with both `posix=False` and `posix=True`:

- Using `posix=False`

```
s1 = shlex.shlex(string, posix=False)
slist1 = list(s1)
print(f'slist1 = {slist1}')
```

Output:

```
slist1 = ['"This is a \\"', 'difficult', '\\', '" problem"', 'please', 'help']
```

- Using `posix=True`

```
s2 = shlex.shlex(string, posix=True)
slist2 = list(s2)
print(f'slist2 = {slist2}')
```

Output:

```
slist2 = ['This is a "difficult" problem', 'please', 'help']
```

In the first case, you can immediately see it does not meet condition #1.

In the second case, it **almost** meets both conditions, but fails to conserve the double-quote around "This is ... problem". I cannot just add them post-split because I have no idea what position is the string in the list and I do **not** want to add the double-quotes to all entries.

Is there a trick for solving this or am I just running into a wall?

I'd really appreciate the help!

Comment: Does [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41026445/6243352) do what you want?

Comment: @ggorlen Thanks but this answer does not split the string

Comment: The approved answer from the following post does what I want but is using re instead of shlex, any chance this can be done in shlex too?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16710076/python-split-a-string-respect-and-preserve-quotes